# Simulink difference between load_system and open_system

Tags: matlab, class, simulink

I have a Simulink model that calls a script in the InitFcn of the Model callbacks. This script initializes a bunch of variables in the base workspace so that they can be used by the Simulink model. When using Classes, I found that using the `load_system` function will make Matlab crash and the `open_system` function will work just fine.

Here the Class:

```
classdef simulinkModel
    properties
        model = '';
    end
    methods
        function obj = simulinkModel(modelName)
            obj.model = modelName;
        end
        function openModel(obj)
            % Make sure any previously open model are closed, and open the model.
            if bdIsLoaded(obj.model)
                obj.closeModel()
            end
            %load_system(obj.model) % Matlab crash
            open_system(obj.model) % Matlab run the model correctly
        end
        function closeModel(obj)
            close_system(obj.model, 0) 
        end
        function runModel(obj)
            sim(obj.model)
        end
    end
end
```

And in the command window:

```
objModel = simulinkModel('test');
objModel.openModel
objModel.runModel
```

So how comes it crashs with the `load_system` vs the `open_system`? Is there something that the `open_system` function do with the base workspace that the `load_system` function doesn't do?

**EDIT**

I decided to try running simple commands outside of the class to see if the problem is elsewhere. So typing in the command window:

```
load_system('test')
sim('test')
```

When executing this in the command window, Matlab will also crash. So I'm starting to wonder if the model callbacks are not executed when the `load_system` function is called.

Comment: What kind of crash? Any error message?

Comment: @Daniel Appcrash I think. Windows error message.

Comment: @Daniel Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: MATLAB.exe
  Application Version: 1.0.0.1
  Application Timestamp: 4b54ec23
  Fault Module Name: libut.dll
  Fault Module Version: 1.0.0.1

Comment: What Release and OS? It works as expected R2013b, Win8.  You say that you're using the InitFcn, so the final sentence of your Edit isn't relevant.  The InitFcn does not get called with either load_system or open_system, rather it gets called when the model is initialized as part of the call to sim.  But either way, it shouldn't cause a seg-fault, rather is would just return an error saying the variables haven't been defined.

Comment: Win7 and Matlab R2010a. I moved the parameters to the PreLoad callback and now everything is working fine. Having the parameters called in the InitFcn clearly created the crash when using `load_system`.

Answer (score -1):

I can confirm there is indeed very different behaviour between load_system and open_system. I am currently debugging a weird problem under 2015b to be, and I just realized the LoadFcn callback of my simulink models is not called when I use load_system, but is is called properly when I use open_system. I don't know that this is documented anywhere.  I find this callback name misleading if it is not called when you "load" the system !!! If I find more info, I will post back on this thread.